# IIS unable to write to disk

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have one server that works (that I originally remember took me a loooong time to figure out--dont remember solution).  I copy the exact same permissions to the new server, and it does not work.  'Everyone' is given total permission.

I have given permissions to _IUSR, IIS_USR, and Everyone., yet I still have errors with PHP trying to write/modify files.

Whats up?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention IIS version you are using and what's application you are trying to run on top of it - these would be helpful to get a proper answer.

Looking at account names you mentioned you are running IIS 7.x... If you are running app which requires some fancy permissions config on its folders and files just try to temporarily grant full access to Everyone and IUSR from the top of app folder (overwriting everything below it) just to verify that this is permissions problem indeed.